# HA Proxy rule - 404 not found

Tags: load-balancing, acl, haproxy

I have configured below rule in HA Proxy. I get 404 not found when I try to hit http://haproxy_ip/service

```
frontend http-in
    bind 10.254.23.225:80
    acl has_service path_beg /service
    use_backend service_server if has_service

backend service_server
    balance roundrobin
    cookie SERVERID insert
    option httpchk HEAD /check.txt HTTP/1.0
    option httpclose
    option forwardfor
    server server1 192.168.2.1:9000 cookie server1 check
```

Comment: Do you have the issue if you call directly `http://192.168.2.1:9000/service` ? If so, your backend doesn't handle correctly your request.

Comment: backend doesnt have /service in itself. I use haproxy to have virutal path in url.

Comment: Thanks it worked with reqrep ^([^\ ]*\ /)service[/]?(.*)     \1\2

Answer (score 1):

> backend doesnt have /service in itself. I use haproxy to have virutal path in url.

With the current configuration, `/service/test.txt` will trigger the acl `has_service` and will send `/service/test.txt` to your backend, without changing the url.

If you want to change the url (proxying `/service` in the frontend to `/` in the backend), you should add the following line in your backend:

```
reqrep ^([^\ ]*)\ /service(.*)  \1\ \2
```

This will remove `/service` from the proxied request.

**Edit:**

HAProxy won't rewrite the html output: your assets won't get a leading `/service/` and won't be served correctly.

When you proxy requests, it is way easier to keep the same path: proxying `/` to `/` or `/myapp/` to `/myapp/` for example. If you proxy `/a` to `/b/c`, the proxy itself will need to rewrite the response: `<img src="/a/test.png">` needs to be changed to `<img src="/b/c/test.png">`. Or [worse](https://serverfault.com/a/561897/367929), `<img src="../c/test.png" />`. Add relative references in html, js and css too. I'm not sure it's doable with HAProxy.

If you can change the application and deploy it on `/service/`, you will avoid **a lot** of issues. Using an other vhost (`service.yourdomain.com` for example) can solve this issue too.

If not, I'm not sure HAProxy is the right tool here, I'd try apache 2.4 with 
[mod_proxy_html](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_html.html) (but not before trying really hard to deploy the app on `/service/`).

Comment: You are right! But the web application has css , images and js files that doesnt get redirected to backend rule. As /service will not be present after first redirection. How to persist the ip and use it in same session for redirection?

Comment: See my update: handling `/services/` (if possible) in your backend would be the easiest solution.